# Почему консоль пикает?

Tags: c#, консоль, текст

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

С чего бы это?

Comment: Что вы хотели сделать этой строкой? Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data))));

Comment: Экспериментировал, забудьте)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

И правда, с чего бы ей пикать при выводе символа с кодом 7 - BEL (Bell, он же звонок)?

Comment: Не уверен, что это корректный ответ (хоть он и правильный)

Comment: Не знал, спасибо. Только не понятно зачем это реализовано. Вроде метод Beep есть

Comment: @DeonixHooh совместимость с DOS, в которой это было для совместимости с CP/M, где это было сделано для совместимости с телетайпами. Может быть цепочка еще длиннее, тут я не в курсе.

Comment: @DeonixHooh если же плясать не от реализации, а от стандартов, то кодировка UTF-8 является ASCII-совместимой, и использует таблицу Unicode, которая, опять-таки, начинается все с той же таблицы ASCII. Таблица же ASCII была разработана для все тех же телетайпов.